# What do I need to import for my "Visitable" interface to work in java?

Tags: java, visitor-pattern

I've a noob question. I can't seem to figure out which import I need to add to my java program in order to get my 'visitable' interface to work (that is to create a visitor design pattern). I tried this:

```
 import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.Visitor;

    public interface Visitable{
          public void accept(Visitor visitor);
        }
```

But it keeps giving me an error saying "The import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.Visitor cannot be resolved".

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) does not have any implementation in the JDK as such.  You are expected to write the components on your own.  You may be able to find something but the Visitor is usually pretty unique to your application.

In other words, the Visitor interface as you have coded does not exist for your app, and you don't need to use an import.